# Install Nvidia GeForce 740M driver in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a laptop with VGA Onboard Intel HD integrated graphics and an Nvidia GeForce 740M graphics processor. How I can install the Nvidia GeForce 740M driver in Ubuntu 12.04? Because, yesterday I can't install it. After restarting my laptop's resolution was 600x480.

Do I have to install that with terminal PPA or by downloading the file from the NVIDIA official website? Please give me solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the current by using

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

or the updates with

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

Since you have a double graphic card configuration, I assume that you will also need to take a look at [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee), which will be useful to switch between the two graphic cards.

Please note that some manufacturers, like Asus, sometimes modify the hardware thay put into their laptops and the stable proprietary drivers simply won't work (I've seen at least 2 cases on the italian forum).

In this case you will need to use the experimental drivers 319 or 325 from the [Xorg edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa). Obviously, since they are experimental, it is possible that you will experience some problems.

Comment: Installing `nvidia-current` without bumblebee on a optimus system, will cause a black screen (or low resolution) which intern will cause another problem to OP. I suggest you to edit this question to make it more useful.

Comment: No, it does not. At least it did not do this thing to me.

On my system I installed `nvidia-current` and it was simply not enabled until I installed also bumblebee and used it.